# Ruby on Rails cannot load concern module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have initialized a module in the folder "concerns" located in:
**appname/app/models/concerns**

called current_cart.rb

**appname/app/models/concerns/current_cart.rb**

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

private

    def set_cart
        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        @cart = Cart.create
        session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
end
```

i'm including this in my controller line_item_controllers:

**appname/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
```

but it produces this error when i try to execute on my browser:

```
uninitialized constant LineItemsController::CurrentCart

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:2:in `<class:LineItemsController>'
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Is `app/models/concerns` in your load_paths?

Comment: Which rails version you are using?

Comment: i'm using a version of rails 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code, I'm assuming you are following along with the book, "Agile Web Development with Rails."

I would recommend just moving your code from:

```
appname/app/models/concerns/current_cart.rb
```

to:

```
appname/app/controllers/concerns/current_cart.rb
```

This would allow you to most easily follow the example in the book.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing seems to be wrong here, if we are talking about Rails 4 - it should work out of the box.

However, what you are doing is a slight misuse of what concerns are for. 
And you are defining `models/concerns`, where you should put this one in `controllers/concerns` (for readability's sake).

For this case, [controller filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) are more suitable.

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart

  private

  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same problem. For me it was a simple bug. It couldn't read `LineItemsController::CurrentCart` because when I created `current_cart.rb` it was saved with an aditional white space at the end (after .rb), .eg `current_cart.rb(space)`

So after deleting the white extra space it all worked out well.

Comment: Mine was similar, I forgot to put .rb at the end of the filename, seeing this helped me find that when I was looking for a space at the end so kudos